# Computing R^2 given cov matrix and R^2 from regression on another parameter

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

Consider the linear regression model with design matrix
$X = [x_1 \mid x_2 \mid \cdots\mid x_p] \in\mathbb R^{n\times p}$. Assume that $x^T_j 1_n = 0$, for $j = 1, \ldots , p$, that is, the columns of $X$ are centered. (Here, and elsewhere $1_n \in\mathbb R^n$ is the vector of all-ones of length $n$). Note that the model does not include an
intercept.

Assume that:

$$
\frac{1}{n}X^TX=\begin{bmatrix}I_{p-1} & z\\z & a^2\end{bmatrix}, z\in R^{p-1}, a^2\in R
$$
where $a^2$ and $z$ are given quantities. Assume that $a^2=10\|z\|^2$.

Let R$^2_j$ be the $R^2$ obtained when regressing x$_j$ onto the rest of covariates $\{x_1, \ldots , x_{j−1}, x_{j+1}, \ldots , x_p\}.$
Find R$^2_p$, that is, the coefficient of determination resulting from regressing $x_p$ onto $\{x_1, \ldots , x_{p−1}\}.$

I'm not really sure how to convert from one $\mathbb R^2$ to another $\mathbb R^2$. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction or towards a formula I can use, as I can't seem to find much helpful information.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Edited. This is a homework question. I can't find the formula I should be using in the textbook we have and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1: Reshape $X$ matrix: $X_{-p} = (x_1,\dots,x_{p-1})$ and $Y=(x_p)$.

2: Find total sum of square of $Y$.

3: Find $\hat\beta = (X_{-p}'X_{-p})^{-1}X_{-p}'Y$

4: Find model SS, which is $\hat Y' \hat Y$ given $\bar Y = 0 $

5: The ratio of model SS to total SS is the $R^2$ that you need.